# Get all values available in x arrays by key into a string

Tags: jquery, arrays, grep

I have this code that its suposed so filter and return all values from an array by date:

```
var resultado = $.grep(data, function(obj) {
  return obj.start === ano + "-" + mes + "-" + diaMes;
});

if (resultado.length > 0) {
  nomeUtilizador = resultado[0].nomeUtilizador;
  totalDias = resultado[0].totalDias;
}

if (totalDias >= 1) {
  for (i = 0; i < totalDias; i++) {
    lista += '<tr><td>' + e + '</td>';
    lista += '<td>' + nomeUtilizador + '</td>';
    lista += '</tr>';

    if (i < totalDias - 1)
      e++;
  }
} else {
  lista += '<tr><td>' + e + '</td>';
  lista += '<td>' + nomeUtilizador + '</td>';
  lista += '</tr>';
}
```

As you see I get an array in the `$.grep(data, function(obj){..`

And in `if (resultado.length > 0)...` I select 0 or 1 eg: `resultado[0].nomeUtilizador`.

What I want is to have all `"nomeUtilizador"` from all the arrays that could possibly exist AND put them in a single string.

Did I make myself clear or I need more explaining? Any help would be awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.map()` : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

Similar to `$.grep()` but returns a transform or flattened result based on the callback, eg:

```
var resultado = $.grep(data, function(obj) {
  return obj.start === ano + "-" + mes + "-" + diaMes;
});

var names = $.map(resultado, function(obj) {
  return obj.nomeUtilizador;
});
```

this will give you an array of all the "nomeUtilizador", which you can then convert to a string as you see fit, eg:

```
console.log(names.join(", "))
lista += "<td>" + names.join("</td><td>") + "</td>";
```